# Disable logging to syslog

Tags: bash, logs, syslog, airmon-ng

I am experimenting with `aircrack-ng` and I managed to fill up `/` with the syslog file complaining about what I'm doing to the poor wifi card. **How can I disable logging to syslog for the duration of my Bash session?**. Of course I would like other, unrelated, processes to continue their logging as necessary.

The `/var/log/syslog` file looks like this, repeating:

```
Oct 24 03:39:40 loathe NetworkManager[673]: <error> [1445647180.233086] [platform/nm-linux-platform.c:2782] do_chan     ge_link(): platform-linux: do-change-link: failure changing link 4: Unspecific failure (1)
Oct 24 03:39:40 loathe wpa_supplicant[762]: Could not set interface mon0 flags (UP): Name not unique on network
Oct 24 03:39:40 loathe wpa_supplicant[762]: nl80211: Could not set interface 'mon0' UP
Oct 24 03:39:40 loathe wpa_supplicant[762]: nl80211: deinit ifname=mon0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Oct 24 03:39:40 loathe wpa_supplicant[762]: Could not set interface mon0 flags (UP): Name not unique on network
Oct 24 03:39:40 loathe wpa_supplicant[762]: WEXT: Could not set interface 'mon0' UP
Oct 24 03:39:40 loathe wpa_supplicant[762]: mon0: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

This is on Kubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Unix, Linux, BSD, ...? syslog, syslog-ng, whatever? More info please.

Comment: @Jan: Kubuntu is a Linux distro, pretty much Ubuntu (Debian-based) with KDE. I'm googling for the answer to the second question, but I'm not sure how to tell. The file in question is `/var/log/syslog`, and this distro version was released just last week so I assume that it uses the new and shiny. In fact, it is SystemD based.

Comment: Maybe someone else here is familiar with the aircrack suite of tools, but if not -- seeing the relevant syslog messages would help us determine their source (and thus appropriate changes to make inside Archemar's answer)

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Thank you, I added example log output to the question.

Comment: I don't have a good way of testing ideas; does adding `-qq` to wpa_supplicant help any? ref: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1323089/comments/39

Comment: @dotancohen: I know whta Kubuntu is, but there wasn't _any_ related information before the edit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

syslog is system wide, so you can't disable syslog on a per session basis.

However, you can

- copy  `/etc/rsyslog.conf` to `/tmp/rsyslog.conf`
- edit  `/tmp/rsyslog.conf` to remove unwanted logging
- kill rsyslogd (`/etc/init.d/rsyslogd stop`)
- run `rsyslogd -d -f /tmp/rsyslog.conf` for the time of your "session"

at the end of the session

- kill rsyslogd (find process with ps)
- run rsyslog  (`/etc/init.d/rsyslogd start`)